# Escape and validation inputs required for two database?

Tags: php, database, wordpress, external, sql-injection

I'm currently working on a WordPress website project and I am hoping someone can help me out on this.

In the registration page, the data entered is stored into the WordPress database. I've also build a connection to store those data into an external database as well. So basically, If a visitor registers on the site, their data info gets stored in the WP and external DB.

My question is since the external DB relies on checking to see if the submit button has been pressed, do those data input values need to be escaped to prevent sql injection?

I know the data submitted to WordPress has already been sql escaped.

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do something like this:

```
INSERT INTO database2.table ... SELECT ... FROM database1.table WHERE ...
```

That way you can cut HTML/PHP out of the process entirely.

Comment: I've decided to use the WordPress action hook user_register to solve the issue. Your solution seems right as well and I'll keep that in mind.